# How to implement a click-away listener in Next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, dom-events

I have a reusable component called DropDown and a custom hook called useClickOutside. I am using context API to track multiple dropdowns using unique ids.

Code for useClickOutside

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { toUSVString } from "util";

export function useClickOutside(callback: () => void) {
  const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleClick(event: MouseEvent) {
      const target = event.target as HTMLDivElement | HTMLButtonElement;
      if (event.target === ref.current) {
        return;
      }

      if (target?.contains(ref.current) && target !== ref.current) {
        console.log("clicked outside");
        callback();
      }
    }

    window && window.addEventListener("click", handleClick, { capture: true });
    return () => {
      window &&
        window.removeEventListener("click", handleClick, { capture: true });
    };
  }, [callback, ref.current]);

  return ref;
}
```

code for DropDown component

```
import { ReactNode } from "react";
import { useClickOutside } from "../../util/hooks/useClickOutside";

export default function DropDown({
  id,
  onOpen,
  onClose,
  isOpen,
  content,
  buttonContent,
}: {
  id: string;
  onOpen: (id: string) => void | undefined;
  onClose: () => void | undefined;
  isOpen: boolean;
  content?: ReactNode;
  buttonContent?: any;
}) {

    let elementRef = useClickOutside(() => {
    if (isOpen) {
      onClose();
    }
  });
  

  return (
    <div className="relative z-30">
      <button
        className="rounded-full p-0 border-2 border-slate-300"
        onClick={() => (isOpen ? onClose() : onOpen(id))}
      >
        {buttonContent}
      </button>
      {isOpen && (
        <div
          ref={elementRef}
          className="absolute space-y-2 right-0 w-56 mt-2 origin-top-right bg-white rounded-lg shadow-xl ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none z-30"
        >
          {content}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Discussion on Nextjs Repository](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/44515)
[Loom with demo](https://www.loom.com/share/e6de04b066c442899f588c9db076f161)

**Current Behavior**
DropDown close when I click outside the element but within the component that wraps around the DropDown component.

**Expected Behavior**
I want the DropDown to close no matter where I click on the entire screen. Whether I click within the wrapping component or any other components, the event should be fired.

Answer (score 2):

You are explicitly saying that you don't want to call the callback when clicking other elements, but what you need to do is, simply skip calling the `callback` when it's not necessary.

```
// useClickOutside.ts
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

export function useClickOutside(callback: () => void) {
  const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleClick(event: MouseEvent) {
      const el = ref?.current;

      // Do nothing if clicking ref's element or descendent elements
      if (!el || el.contains(event.target as Node)) {
        return;
      }

      callback();
    }

    window?.addEventListener("click", handleClick, { capture: true });
    return () => {
      window?.removeEventListener("click", handleClick, { capture: true });
    };
  }, [callback, ref.current]);

  return ref;
}
```